# Save matrix in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
for c=1:10;
D = maximin(n2,n1,'euclidean');
M = min(D,[],2); ;
C=[D M]; 
[maxValue, rowIdx] = max(C(:,end),[],1); %max value and the row index
n1(end+1,:) = n2(rowIdx,:); %Copy selected row to bottom of n1
n2(rowIdx,:) = []; %Delete the row from n2 that has the maximin
c=c+1;
end
```

n1 is 50*80 and n2 is 100*80 At the end of first iteration n1=51*80 and n2=49*80 and so on. I need to see save the n1 at the end of each iteration, so that I can use n1(1) ... n1(10) for further calculation. Please help. I tried the following

```
B = cell(1, c); B(n) = n1(1, c+1); and
B{n} = n1;
```

Didn't help. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What error message did you get? Where in the loop did you place the second piece of code?

Comment: I placed it right above the "c=c+1" statement. I don't get an error when using B{n}., instead I get a 1* 10 matrix in which each cell consists of n's (n1..n10 in 10 cells). Its like whole n1 matrix is in one cell of B{n}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should preallocate `B` before the loop as follows:

```
B = cell(10, 1);
```

and in each iteration of the loop you store `n1` in `B` like so:

```
B{c} = n1;
```

Then you can access `n1` computed the any iteration using the same syntax. For example, matrix `n1` calculated in the the third iteration is `B{3}`.

Comment: Sorry, it's not letting me upvote :(  I have another external loop k=50,100 and 150. I generate 10 values each for k =50,100.150. Is it possible to represent B{c}{k}?